# Why does Cordova Android app throw this warning: “[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event…”?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, touchstart

When running “cordova run android” from the CLI, the Cordova-based app successfully opens and displays on the test phone.  However, when touching any part of the screen (whether it’s a UI element or not), the following warning is displayed in the Chrome DevTools / WebView console:

> “[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with
>   cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and
>   cannot be interrupted.”

The warning points to: `app.min.js:5341`. This line reads: `y.preventDefault()`.

No other errors or warnings are displayed.

As a result of this issue, the app and all its UI elements are unusable.

This issue does **not** occur on the first use of the app after installation. Instead, the issue occurs on the second and all subsequent uses of the app.

Just in case this information is relevant: the “app.js” mobile UI framework is being used in this app.  app.js JavaScript-based controllers (rather than jQuery) are being used: http://code.kik.com/app/2/docs.html#pages-controllers.

Are there any suggestions for resolving or debugging this issue?  Thanks!